# crear objeto a partir de un arreglo de arreglos

Tags: javascript, array, objeto

hola tengo un problema con algo aquí que no soy capas de solucionar espero me puedan ayudar
ya he buscado mucho y no logro hacer nada.

```
let arreglo = [
['_Miss_Roggers'],
['16.54'],
 ['1ViolletSmith'],
['14.31'],
['abbySex4U'],
['0.00'],
['AbrilCarolina'],
['6.19'],
['Adriana__Lima'],
['0.53'], 
['AlexaColins'],
['2.82'],
['AlexaTaylor'],
['44.82'],
['AlissaLatin'],
['12.99'],
['AllisonTaylor'],
['0.00'],
['AlyshaBrowne'],
['4.77'],
['Alyx_Rossexxx'],
['1.12'],
['AmbarSmith'],
['0.00'],
['AmberMorris'],
['0.00'],
['AnastasiaXU'],
['1.31'],
['AngelaDevilis'], 
['0.00'],
['AnnaWestss'],
['0.00'],
['AnnieSmith'], 
['0.00'],
['AntonellaSmily'],
['0.00'], 
['AntonyStuar'], 
['0.64'],
['Aranxa_Submissive'],
['3.54'],
['Atlamty-Avi'],
['0.00']
];
let objeto;
let g;
for (let i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++){
  g = i % 2;
  ace = Object.assign({
    if (g === 0){ User: arreglo[i], }
    else{ Creditos: arreglo[i]}
  });
  objeto.push(ace);
}
return objeto;
}
console.log(arregloaobjetoobjeto())
/* necesito hacer algo asi => let objeto = [
    {User: '_Miss_Roggers', Creditos: '16.54'},
    {User: '1ViolletSmith', Creditos: '14.31'},
    {User: 'abbySex4U', Creditos: '0.00'},
    {User: 'AbrilCarolina', Creditos: '6.19'},
    {User: 'Adriana__Lima', Creditos: '0.53'}, 
    {User: 'AlexaColins', Creditos: '2.82'},
    {User: 'AlexaTaylor', Creditos: '44.82'},
    {User: 'AlissaLatin', Creditos: '12.99'},
    {User: 'AllisonTaylor', Creditos: '0.00'},
    {User: 'AlyshaBrowne', Creditos: '4.77'},
    {User: 'Alyx_Rossexxx', Creditos: '1.12'},
    {User: 'AmbarSmith', Creditos: '0.00'},
    {User: 'AmberMorris', Creditos: '0.00'},
    {User: 'AnastasiaXU', Creditos: '1.31'},
    {User: 'AngelaDevilis', Creditos: '0.00'},
    {User: 'AnnaWestss', Creditos: '0.00'},
    {User: 'AnnieSmith', Creditos: '0.00'},
    {User: 'AntonellaSmily', Creditos: '0.00'}, 
    {User: 'AntonyStuar', Creditos: '0.64'},
    {User: 'Aranxa_Submissive', Creditos: '3.54'},
    {User: 'Atlamty-Avi', Creditos: '0.00'}
    ];*/
```

he hecho eso pero obviamente no ha funcionado creando el if en el Object.assign
y si lo hago sin el if me crea un objeto por cada elemento del arreglo.
necesito algo como lo que puse debajo del console.log todo esos datos vienen de untextarea.value que ya limpiado hasta ese punto que no soy capas de crear el objeto o si me puede ayudar a que arreglo sea de la siguiente forma [['_Miss_Roggers', 16.54], ['1ViolletSmith', 14.31] y así con el resto de datos] y lo resolvería yo con el object.assign o un reduce pero aquí realmente no fui capas desde ya le agradezco al que se tome la molestia de revisar esto muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo único que tienes que hacer es un bucle que salte de 2 en 2 casillas de tu array y ir definiendo tu nuevo array de objetos.

```
function transformar(arr) {
  const objeto = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
    const user = arr[i][0];
    const creditos = arr[i+1][0];
    objeto.push({ User: user, Creditos: creditos });
  }
  return objeto;
}
```

Como ves, al saltar de 2 en 2 siempe será que

```
user = arr[i][0]
creditos = aarr[i+1][0]
```

Por supuesto puedes abreviar el contenido del for así:

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
  objeto.push({ User: arr[i][0], Creditos: arr[i+1][0] });
}
```

Lo del [0] es necesario por que si no la salida te daría un:

```
{ User: [ '_Miss_Roggers' ], Creditos: [ '16.54' ] }
```

Así que pon el [0] para que te de la salida que buscas:

```
{ User: '_Miss_Roggers', Creditos: '16.54' },
{ User: '1ViolletSmith', Creditos: '14.31' },
{ User: 'abbySex4U', Creditos: '0.00' }
// ...etc
```

Comment: muchas gracias perfecto funciono en su totalidad muchas gracias

Comment: Perfecto entonces! Dale click a respuesta válida/aceptada así que cierra el hilo. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Está implementando mal la lógica. ace(?) esta al aire...  además `Object.assign` no recibe condicionales y según el if (que no funcionará) solo asignaría *user* o *créditos* y también es innecesario ya que solo debe extraer en pares: [1] posición user y [2] créditos, para asignarlos al objeto:

```
let objeto = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i += 2) {
  let user = arreglo[i][0]; // Será: User
  let creditos = arreglo[i+1][0]; //Será: Creditos
  
  let ace = Object.assign({}, { User: user, Creditos: creditos });
  
  objeto.push(ace); 
}

console.log(objeto);
```